# Call a method after jobss started

Tags: jboss, struts2, servlet-filters, dispatcher

Hi i am using struts 2 and want to call a method just after when server is up.
as on server startup we can use FILTER DISPATCHER. 
i am using jax ws . and i am deploying my jax client and endpoint project  on same jboss server.
How to solve this
Plz help

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a `ServletContextListener` to respond to the servlet starting up.

Create your implementation like so:

```
public class SimpleInitializer implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //Place your startup logic here.
    }
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

Then, include it in the web.xml, like so:

```
<listener>
    <display-name>SIMPLE Startup Listener</display-name>
    <listener-class>com.you.init.SimpleInitializer</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: When your server starts up, it will go through the listeners in the web.xml and call their contextInitialized() methods, so you can be sure that your startup logic will execute as soon as the server starts.

Comment: That's what the ServletContextListener is for- after you deploy your project to JBoss, JBoss starts your project up and calls your Listener classes, whatever you put in the contextInitialized() method will be called after server startup and after the project is deployed. Have you given it a try?

Comment: i am using jax ws . and i am deploying my jax client and server on one jboss server. so my client require the server project deployed before it sets some data calling particular method

Comment: You kind of left out the important detail that you're deploying 2 projects on the server... In that case, if you want your client to interface with your server project, I suggest you just periodically "ping" your server until it's up, throwing an error if the server is still down, and retrying again, after some time.

Comment: Just do your usual webservice call and catch the network/io error when it fails to connect to your server. You can handle the error however you want to, like retrying again.

Comment: what if i have one server and i am deploy my client and endpoint on the same server

Comment: You should probably modify your original question with the info you provided in the comments, so more people can help. You original question doesn't have the details we need to answer you

Answer (score 1):

```
MBeanServerConnection server = (MBeanServerConnection)new InitialContext().lookup("jmx/rmi/RMIAdaptor");
ObjectName on = new ObjectName("jboss.system:type=Server");
Object var = server.getAttribute(on, "Started");
System.out.println(**var**);
```

One more thing you can do is run a thread and check the value of `var` in Filter Dispatcher. If it is true then call the web service and set the data into your Servlet Context, otherwise sleep the thread for a particular amount of time. Once the value you have retrieved Stop this thread.

Answer (score 0):

// By Gaurav Kumar(SE at Skilrock Technology)

```
    try{
    MBeanServerConnection server = (MBeanServerConnection)new InitialContext().lookup("jmx/rmi/RMIAdaptor");
    ObjectName on = new ObjectName("jboss.system:type=Server");
    Object var = server.getAttribute(on, "Started");
    System.out.println(var);

        String serverURL = "http://gaurav-compaq-presario-c700-notebook-pc:8080/WServer?wsdl";
        String message = "gaurav";
        HashMap env = new HashMap();
        String[] creds = new String[1];
        creds[0] = message;
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(serverURL);
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
           // Remember to call jmxc.close() when you are done with server connection.
        MBeanServerConnection server1 = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
          System.out.println(server.getAttribute(new ObjectName("MyDomain:key=property"), "AnAttribute"));
          server.invoke(new ObjectName("MyDomain:key=property"), "doSomething", new Object[0], new String[0]);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: You can do this task by getting the server information at server start up and call your particular web service URL from FilterDispatcher Java File . I have done the same scenario with the help of this following code.